# Will deleting my GitHub organization break redirects for a previously transferred repository?

Tags: github

I created an organization owning one repository in GitHub Enterprise 2.9. I then transferred the repository to another organization. Redirects are working; e.g. `/old-org/repo/issues/123` redirects to `/new-org/repo/issues/123`.

I'd like to remove the original, now-empty organization (`old-org`). If I do that, will redirects from `/old-org/repo` to `/new-org/repo` still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it. It works as expected - the `old-org` organization is deleted, but `/old-org/repo/issues/123` still redirects to `/new-org/repo/issues/123`.

Case closed.